# Python searching in few specific / latest dirs instead of all using os.walk

Tags: python

I'm new here but have been here for a while trying to learn python. I was searching for hours now to come up with solution then was searching for a while and unfortunately have to give up. Wrapping it up:

I needed to write code to find files with specific names and later on merge them (pdf). Everything works great if i don't expand path with 'finaldir' BUT: there are alot of dirs with date like in 'finaldir' and i want my script to only search in dirs named as in finaldir and in range of -x days from it.

Example: finaldir = '2020-02-04' Script should look in folders named: '2020-02-04', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-01', '2020-01-31', '2020-01-30' ... etc.

```
 finaldir = '2020-02-04'     #this is example, Script get data from excel workbook

            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Python\testfiles\haha'+'\\'+ str(finaldir)):
                for dir in dirs:
                    if dir == 'asd' or dir == 'qwe':                      #script get 1 file from each folder

                        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, dir)):
                            if regex1.match(file) or regex2.match(file):          #patterns for file 1 and 2
                                pdf_files.append(os.path.join(path, dir, file))   #appends list for pdfmerge
```

I am new to programming so any suggestion would be very apprecieted.

Thanks for you time and help.

Ps. Folder names are also when folder was created if it will help get solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
for dir in dirs:
    if dir != finaldir:
        continue
```

Also, your os.listdir() is probably unnecessary - you could just iterate over files.

Also, if you see a directory with a deep hierarchy beneath it which you know you don't want to fully traverse, you can remove it from dirs.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I feel like i made it too chaotic. I need script to search only x latest dirs for example if x = 5: '2020-02-04', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-01', '2020-01-31' if x = 6: '2020-02-04', '2020-02-03', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-01', '2020-01-31' etc. ''if dir == 'asd' or dir == 'qwe':"  part is important because later on script use another key with different dir names but only if  script won't find anything.